# vb.net regex for capture date of expiration billing

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm not familiar with regular expression, how to convert this html view page source into regex

```
"Your next bill is for <b class=\"recurring-price\">\u00a39.99<\/b> on <b class=\"recurring-date\">27\/01\/2020<\/b>."}
```

Because i want to capture the expiration date of billing

Here's my code in vb.net

```
Dim overview As String = req.Post("https://www.sample.com/uk/account/overview/").ToString()
Dim pay As Match = Regex.Match(overview, "capture of expiration billing from regex")
TextBox1.Text = "Your next bill: " & pay.Groups(1).Value
```

Comment: Get a HTML parser. Don't "parse" HTML with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Best not to use `RegEx` for parsing HTML. You'll end up chasing your tail and pulling your hair out.

Use [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) instead. You can find the NuGet package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/).

**--EDIT--**

Here's an example:

```
Public Sub Agility()
  Dim oDocument As New HtmlDocument
  Dim oResult As IEnumerable(Of HtmlNode)
  Dim dDate As Date

  oDocument.LoadHtml("<html><body>Your next bill is for <b class='recurring-price'>39.99</b> on <b class='recurring-date'>01/01/2020</b></body></html>")
  oResult = oDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("b").Where(Function(Node) Node.HasClass("recurring-date"))

  If Date.TryParse(oResult.First.InnerText, dDate) Then
    ' Prints 1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
    Console.WriteLine(dDate)
  End If

  Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

You can find many more [here](https://html-agility-pack.net/online-examples).

Comment: So i'll already installed html agility pack, can you provide an example for parsing html view page source to capture this "Your next bill is for <b class=\"recurring-price\">\u00a39.99<\/b> on <b class=\"recurring-date\">27\/01\/2020<\/b>."}